# Using WriteCodeFragment MSBuild Task

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuild-propertygroup

I am trying to use the `WriteCodeFragment` MSBuild task to create an `AssemblyVersion` attribute. I'm having a problem creating a property group to correctly pass the `ITaskItem` array required for processing. Can someone help with an example?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This creates a file called `BuildVersion.cs` with an `AssemblyVersion` attribute of `123.123.123.123`. If `OutputFile` is removed then a randomly generated file name will be used instead. The `Compile` item name automatically adds the item to the Compile items (includes `BuildVersion.cs` in the build). The `FileWrites` item name allows the file to be removed during Clean.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <ItemGroup>
     <AssemblyAttributes Include="AssemblyVersion">
       <_Parameter1>123.123.123.123</_Parameter1>
     </AssemblyAttributes>
  </ItemGroup>
  <WriteCodeFragment AssemblyAttributes="@(AssemblyAttributes)"
                     Language="C#"
                     OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)"
                     OutputFile="BuildVersion.cs">
    <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="Compile" />
    <Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="FileWrites" />
  </WriteCodeFragment>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. It's worth noting also that you need to add BuildVersion.cs to the Compile item as well. `<ItemGroup><Compile Include="BuildVersion.cs" /></ItemGroup>`

Comment: I've updated the code to automatically add the output to the Compile items.

Comment: In a C# project, adding `Output TaskParameter="OutputFile" ItemName="FileWrites" />` to the content of the `WriteCodeFragment` element lets the file be removed upon `Clean`.

Comment: Without specifying `OutputFile="BuildVersion.cs"`, the task will generate a new unique file name each time it is called.

Comment: How can I do this but in .net core 3.1?

Comment: how would you add 
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Namespace.OfYourUnitTest.Project")]
if you needed to add testing of internals when using moq  to mock up a dependancy? You cant keep making everything public :/