# Access to property variable from .vcsproj at compile time for C++ CLI program in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, custom-attributes

I want to get access to variable from .vcsproj at compile time.

main.cpp:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace cli;

[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets::Assembly)]
ref class Attr sealed : public Attribute {
public:
    Attr(String^ _value) { value = _value; }
    String^ value;
};

int main()
{
    Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::GetEntryAssembly();
    array<Object^>^ assemblyArray = assembly->GetCustomAttributes(Attr::typeid, true);
    Attr^ attr = dynamic_cast<Attr^>(assemblyArray->GetValue(0));
    String^ value = attr->value; // value != "myValue"
    return 0;
}
```

Fragment of VisualStudio project file:

project_name.vcsproj.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="ClassLibrary1.Attr">
      <_Parameter1>"myValue"</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Obviously I don't understand enough how attributes works but I can't even reproduce solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522751/how-to-read-get-a-propertygroup-value-from-a-csproj-file-using-c-sharp-in-a-ne/49537163#49537163) post.
How to make it work?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522751/how-to-read-get-a-propertygroup-value-from-a-csproj-file-using-c-sharp-in-a-ne/49537163#49537163)  solution but somehow it doesn't work for me..